# Change password on multiple servers with chpasswd

Tags: server, bash, scripts

I would like to change the passwd on multiple servers using a for loop.

The problem Is I have to enter sudo passwd for every server(100+)

This is the command I have, but it isn't working,

```
for i in `cat hosts`
do
    ssh user@${i} 'echo user:newpassword | 
                    sudo -S  <<< "sudopasswd" /usr/sbin/chpasswd'
done
```

Any help would be happily received.

Thanks

Comment: i suggest using ansible for this type of work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input redirections and here-strings are placed incorrectly. You are giving the here-string "sudopasswd" to the standard input of `sudo -S`, which takes precedence over piping the echo output (which gets lost this way).

What you can do is to let `sudo` start a Bash shell and run the `echo` and `chpasswd` pipeline in there, separating them from the rest:

```
ssh user@${i} 'sudo -S  <<< "sudopasswd" /bin/bash -c "echo user:newpassword |
                                                        /usr/sbin/chpasswd"'
```

Comment: You sir are my hero :D